# MySQL query to get array of averages of each month's data

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have a table named `historical_currencies_rate` where I have saved last 8 years currency rate of some known currencies. eg (EUR-USD). Table looks like this

```
+---------------------------+---------------+------------+
|       rate_date           | currency_pair |    rate    |
+---------------------------+---------------+------------+
|       2006-01-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1797    |
|       2006-02-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1826    |
|       2006-03-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1875    |
|       2006-04-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2083    |
|       2006-05-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2088    |
|       2006-06-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2093    |
|       2006-07-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2093    |
|       2006-08-01          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2093    |
|       2006-01-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-02-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-03-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-04-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-05-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-06-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-07-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-08-01          |    JPY-USD    |  0.01275   |
|       2006-01-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-02-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-03-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-04-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-05-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-06-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-07-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-08-01          |    GBP-USD    |  1.559     |
|       2006-01-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-02-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-03-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-04-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-05-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-06-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-07-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-08-01          |    AUD-USD    |  1.0515    |
|       2006-01-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2092    |
|       2006-02-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2066    |
|       2006-03-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2061    |
|       2006-04-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2061    |
|       2006-05-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.2061    |
|       2006-06-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1981    |
|       2006-07-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1973    |
|       2006-08-02          |    EUR-USD    |  1.1948    |
+---------------------------+---- ----------+------------+
```

here I have shown you tha data of few currency upto 8 days and for year 2006 but i have a huge data of 18 currencies with 30 days data upto 2013.

My query is that I want an array which contains the avg currency rate of a particular currency on monthly basis. for eg avg of `EUR-USD` in my example for the month of `January` is  `1.19935`, `JPY-USD` is `0.01275`, `GBP-USD` is `1.559` and avg of `EUR-USD` for the month of `February` is `1.2030375` etc.

I want array of averages of `EUR-USD` or may be some other currency pair, of each month ie. it should be like

```
`[1.19935, 1.2030375, ......]`
```

query-result = [avg. of `EUR-USD` for `January, 2006` , avg. of `EUR-USD` for `February, 2006`, ............., avg. of `EUR-USD` for `January, 2013`, ..... ] and so on up to 8 years.

Please help me in writing this in single query.Thanks

Comment: select avg(rate) ... group by currency_pair ,year(rate_date)*12+month(rate_date) ?

Comment: @ArmelLarcier Yes I tried `SELECT avg(rate) as avg FROM `historical_currencies_rate` WHERE (month >= '2006-01-01' and month <= '2006-02-01' and currency_pair = `EUR-USD`)` but that gives me 1 month avg.

Comment: 8 x 18 x 365 = 52560 !! My friend, we have very different definitions of 'huge'. This is 'tiny'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take parts of date you want (in your case year and month) and group result on this base and currency:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rate_date,'%M, %Y') AS rate_month,currency_pair,AVG(rate) AS avg_rate 
FROM historical_currencies_rate
WHERE currency_pair='EUR-USD'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rate_date,'%M, %Y'),currency_pair
ORDER BY rate_month
```

Comment: You are some what right but I need some what like this `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rate_date,'%Y-%M') AS rate_month,currency_pair,AVG(rate) AS avg_rate FROM historical_currencies_rate where currency_pair='EUR-USD' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rate_date,'%M-%Y'),currency_pair;` but order by `Jan2006, Feb2006, ...., Jan2013`. Thanks